# Kendo Scheduler RecurrenceEditorFor set Start to selected Date

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

I have made a CustomEditorTemplate for a Scheduler. And there is one thing that does not work as expected.

For the RecurrenceEditorFor, it has an End On, where you can select a date. But for our RecurrenceEditorFor, it has automatically set the Start to the current date, and not the selected date of the scheduler.

Our RecurrenceEditorFor looks like:

```
<div data-container-for="recurrenceRule" class="k-edit-field">
      @(Html.Kendo().RecurrenceEditorFor(model => model.RecurrenceRule).Messages(m => SchedulerHelper.MessageLocaliztion(this, m))
      .HtmlAttributes(new { data_bind = "value:recurrenceRule" })
      )
</div>
```

I could, of cause set the Start to a specific date,

```
<div data-container-for="recurrenceRule" class="k-edit-field">
      @(Html.Kendo().RecurrenceEditorFor(model => model.RecurrenceRule).Messages(m => SchedulerHelper.MessageLocaliztion(this, m))
      .HtmlAttributes(new { data_bind = "value:recurrenceRule" })
      .Start(new DateTime(2014,8,4))
      )
</div>
```

, but this would not work, if I select a date before this one.

EVEN if I select a date after this current date, it will give me this date. So it is not because this current date is a minimum, but it must be a static date, set somewhere, or somehow.

I have also tried to set the text in the input field with some JavaScript, but this will not make it possible to select a date before the current date. And this will also mess up the RecurrenceRule.

I can see it works as standard, but not for us, after we have added the CustomEditorTemplate. Do we miss something, or made something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around for this:

I added a click method on the Recurrencerule div:

```
$("div[name='RecurrenceRule']").on("click", function () {
    window.changerecurrenceStart();
 });
```

and the metho`changerecurrenceStart` :

```
  function changerecurrenceStart()
{
    var date = $("#startDate").data("kendoDatePicker")._value;

        $("#RecurrenceRule").data("kendoRecurrenceEditor").options.start = date;
        $("#RecurrenceRule").data("kendoRecurrenceEditor").options.value = date;        

}
```

This worked well for me.